# processing group of rows from spark dataset in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, window-functions, apache-spark-dataset

I am looking for a way to divide my large spark dataset into groups/batches and process that group of rows in some function. So basically group of rows should be input to my function and output is Unit for me as I dont want to aggregate or update input records but just perform some calculation.

Just to understand, lets say I have following input.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 1 | C | 3 |
| 1 | A | 4 |
| 1 | A | 5 |
| 2 | C | 6 |
| 2 | X | 7 |
| 2 | X | 8 |

and lets say I need to group by col1 and col2, which will give me following groups

(1,A,1), (1,A,4), (1,A,5) ---> first group

(1, B, 2) ---> Second group

(1, C, 3), (1, C, 6)---> 3rd group

(2, X, 7), (2, X, 8) ---> 4th group

So I want to pass these groups to my function to perform some logic. For now, lets just say I am summing Col3 in that method.(this is not my requirement but lets just assume that I want to do that summation in my separate method). To generate following o/p.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 1 | C | 9 |
| 2 | X | 15 |

How can I achieve this, based on some suggestions, I tried to look at UDAF but couldnt find a way  how to use it. Pls Note that my real input dataset is having more than 500 million records. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple example based on your input to get you started:

```py
    from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    
    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    
    data = [
        (1, "A",  1),
        (1, "B",  2),
        (1, "C",  3),
        (1, "A",  4),
        (1, "A",  5),
        (1, "C",  6),
        (2, "X",  7),
        (2, "X",  8),
    ]
    
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["col1", "col2", "col3"])
    df.show()
    
    +----+----+----+
    |col1|col2|col3|
    +----+----+----+
    |   1|   A|   1|
    |   1|   B|   2|
    |   1|   C|   3|
    |   1|   A|   4|
    |   1|   A|   5|
    |   1|   C|   6|
    |   2|   X|   7|
    |   2|   X|   8|
    +----+----+----+
    
    # define your function - pure Python here, no Spark needed
    def dummy_f(xs):
      return sum(xs)
    
    
    # apply your function as UDF - needs input function and return type (integer here)
    (
      df
      .groupBy(F.col("col1"), F.col("col2"))
      .agg(F.collect_list(F.col("col3").cast("int")).alias("col3"))
      .withColumn("col3sum", F.udf(dummy_f, IntegerType())(F.col("col3")))
    ).show()
    
    +----+----+---------+-------+
    |col1|col2|     col3|col3sum|
    +----+----+---------+-------+
    |   1|   A|[1, 4, 5]|     10|
    |   1|   B|      [2]|      2|
    |   1|   C|   [3, 6]|      9|
    |   2|   X|   [7, 8]|     15|
    +----+----+---------+-------+
```

Aggregating columns as needed for your input function is the key. You can use `create_map` to create a dict or `collect_list` as shown here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This does works if my requirement is summation. But lets say, my requirement is like, within each group. if rows satisfy certain condition then create new record. So lets say for Group [(1,A,1),(1,A,4),(1,A,5)].. lets say requirement is if for each row if col3/sum(col3) > 0.25 this condition is true, then create new record for such rows. So for this group, i want to obtain (1,A,4) & (1,A,5) in separate datastructure. Hence I was looking for a way to somehow receive all rows of a group in a function as a input. Do you think how this can be achieved.?

Comment: Yes, sure. In the example `dummy_f` takes one arg "col3", but you can design any function you want, with any number of args because at this stage you have access to all columns, not juste "col3". ie. `F.udf(complex_f, IntegerType())(F.col("col1"), F.col("col2"), F.col("col3")))` or even a literal.
Juste to be clear, you input column names, but the UDF function will process rows, like `complex_f(row1 of col1, row1 of col2, row1 of col3)` etc.

Comment: Also, try do decompose a lot, it's easier. Like, stage 1: process rows with UDF, output result or None for example, then stage 2: filter out rows without output, group them, etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointers. I will try this approach and reply back here. Thanks alot for assistance :)